# Styling react native components

Tags: react-native, styling

When I run following code on my phone

```
render() {
    return [
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Search />
      </View>,
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.products}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductCard product={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>,
    ];
  }
```

I am getting screen split between Search and Productcard component. It feels like each one of them takes by default 50% of screen, but I want them to come one after each other.

Search component is just a dummy text:

```
export default function Search() {
  return <Text>Hej</Text>;
}
```

But when I remove  around them it looks good.

Comment: can you remove flex:1 from both the views in the above code and then check.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Search />
          </View>,
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <FlatList
              style={styles.list}
              data={this.state.products}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductCard product={item} />}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to make them scroll, if so you have to wrap them around a `<ScrollView>`.

like so,

```
render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Search />
      </View>,
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.products}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductCard product={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

And in second case if you want only the second half to be scrollable just wrap that view inside a `<ScrollView>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for helping, it got me in right direction but I got it working by code below:

```
     <View>
        <Search />,
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.products}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductCard product={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
        ,
      </View>
```